# Does Ion Android library supports hindi text?

Tags: java, android, json, multipart, android-ion

I am using Ion library and sending data android app to server. I pasted hindi font in story editview but while receiving at server, text changed in symbols.

**Android code:**

```
           Ion.with(Createfunction.this)
            .load(url)
            .setTimeout(60 * 1000)
            /*added by sash 16.4.2016*/                   
            .setMultipartParameter("story", story) 
            .setMultipartContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8")                  
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject jsonObject) {
                    commonMethods.dismissWithCheck(materialDialog);
                    if (e == null) {
                      Log.d("oncomplete...", e + "it is null");
                        Boolean success = jsonObject.get("success").getAsBoolean();
                        if (success) {
                        //successfully done
                        }
                    }
            });
```

**Wireshark response:**

[image]

**Hindi pasted text:**

```
चलते लगातार दूसरे दिन एक भी गेंद नहीं फेंकी जा सकी. बारिश को देखते हुए अंपायरों ने तीसरे दिन भी खेल रद्द घोषित कर दिया.
```

**Receiving text like....**

[image]

Please suggest some solution .

Comment: Is hindi utf-8 compliant?

Comment: yes, while sending to server it change in symbols

Comment: Looks like unicode